# GTMBase64 is missing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have added `GTMBase64.h` and `GTMBase64.m` file into my project.

However i can't use `GTMBase64` in my code.

It only show `GTM_INLINE` instead of `GTMBase64`.

Is there any framework i need to add to use `GTMBase64`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: And you have `#import "GTMBase64.h"` in your header or implementation file?

Comment: yes , i imported like that. However it still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got solution for my own question.

Here is complete solution if you want to use `GTMBase64` in your project.

First download two `GTMBase64.h`  and `GTMBase64.m` file.

[GTMBase64.h](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMBase64.h?r=373)

[GTMBase64.m](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMBase64.m?r=87)

and download another file too.

[GTMDefines.h](http://google-toolbox-for-mac.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/GTMDefines.h)

And then add these three files into your project and run it. (remove autorelease if needed).

After that , you can use `GTMBase64`.

Comment: I know this is old, but don't those files depend on other files, which depend on other files, and so on ?   Is there a way to just strip it down for just the base64 stuff without having to include the entire library ?