# user undeclared identifier 'GTMBase64' in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Today my task is to send  local image to Web server through JSON Url
                                                                                                        so i am trying to convert image  to  GTMBase64 and then pass to NSString and then
finally  pass  NSString Value  to my URL

my Problem is

user undeclared identifier 'GTMBase64' in ios i have imported GTMBase64.h and GTMBase64.m Files

but stile it's showing Undeclared identifier GTMBase64

so Give me any Idea about my Problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [GTMBase64 is missing in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251646/gtmbase64-is-missing-in-ios)

Comment: @Kreiri thanks for answered but to how to Declared GTMBase64 please help me